# windowWidth windowHeight not working in iOS

Tags: javascript, ios, browser, html5-canvas, p5.js

I've written a P5JS sketch which is not resizing properly on iPhone13 - it runs fine on other smartphones. On the iPhone it just appears as a tiny sketch a couple of cm wide in the top left corner. Here is the code - the sketch is a fixed ratio in size and always as tall as it can be.

I think windowWidth, windowHeight are not being properly dealt with by iOS? Or is it a CSS issue, or is it pixelDensity? I'd like to solve this without using jQuery or anything like that.

Thanks

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <title>Sketch</title>
    <script src="libraries/p5.min.js"></script>
    <script src="libraries/p5.dom.js"></script>
    <script src="mobile.js"></script>
    <style>
        body {
            color: #fff;
            background-color: #aaa;
            font: 20px Mono, sans-serif;
        }
        div.sketch {
            position: fixed;
            top:0;
            left:0;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="sketch"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

```
function setup() { 
  cnv = createCanvas(450,800); 
  cnv.parent('sketch');

  pixelDensity(1);
  windowResized();
}


function windowResized() {
  //the sketch is a fixed ratio and always as tall as can be
  nh = windowHeight;
  nw = nh * 900 / 1600;
  resizeCanvas(nw,nh);
}


function draw() { 
  background(0);

  noFill();
  strokeWeight(nh*0.1);
  stroke(255);
  rect(0,0,width,height);
}
```

Comment: Are you sure it works on other iPhones / hi-density android phones? You could try adding `defer` so you are sure P5 is loaded before your script executes: `<script defer src="mobile.js">`. The `pixelDensity` setting should not be needed. What happens if you `console.log` the windowWidth/height?

Comment: well it seems to work OK on Responsinator. I don't have a iPhone13 to test on. All I can say is when someone tried to load it up they got a tiny sized sketch.

Comment: OK but your question suggested it does work on other phones. Sadly the responsive design view in desktop browsers is not the same as working on an actual phone, since the screen DPI cannot be exactly emulated. Have you tried the suggestions in my previous comment? Also double check that you have the `<meta viewport>` tag.

Comment: yes it works fine on android phones - its been running in a show for a while. it didn't work on iPhone13 and I heard but didn't see it also wouldn't run on other iPhones. Perhaps there was something else to blame - a javascript library issue? - I have stripped away a lot of the code here for simplicity. Maybe I've stripped away the problem.